# where is the last pool object gone from the display and or if what is the error/exception in my code??

Tags: objective-c

---

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "REFERENCE.h"
int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) 
{
    //POOL CREATION DEPARTMENT
    NSLog(@"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tPOOL CREATION DEPARTMENT");
    NSAutoreleasePool *p=[[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init],
    *p1=[[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init],*p2=[[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init],
    *p3=[[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init],*p4=[[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tRC=%d of p=%@\n\n",[p retainCount],p);
    NSLog(@"RC=%d of p1=%@\n\n",[p1 retainCount],p1);
    NSLog(@"RC=%d of p2=%@\n\n",[p2 retainCount],p2);
    NSLog(@"RC=%d of p3=%@\n\n",[p3 retainCount],p3);
    NSLog(@"RC=%d of p4=%@\n\n",[p4 retainCount],p4);

    //OBJECT CREATION DEPARTMENT
    NSLog(@"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tOBJECT CREATION DEPARTMENT\n\n");
     REFERENCE *rc=[[REFERENCE alloc] init],
    *rc1=[[REFERENCE alloc] init],*rc2=[[REFERENCE alloc] init],
    *rc3=[[REFERENCE alloc] init],*rc4=[[REFERENCE alloc] init];

        [rc autorelease];[rc1 autorelease];[rc2 autorelease];
        [rc3 autorelease];[rc4 autorelease];

    //DELETING DEPARTMENT
    NSLog(@"\n\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tDELETION DEPARTMENT");
    [p1 release];
    NSLog(@"\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tRC=%d of p=%@\n\n",[p retainCount],p);
    NSLog(@"RC=%d of p1=%@\n\n",[p1 retainCount],p1);
    NSLog(@"RC=%d of p2=%@\n\n",[p2 retainCount],p2);
    NSLog(@"RC=%d of p3=%@\n\n",[p3 retainCount],p3);
    NSLog(@"RC=%d of p4=%@\n\n",[p4 retainCount],p4);

    return 0;
}
```

---

The O/P is,-

> [Session started at 2011-07-29 12:27:11 +0530.] 2011-07-29
>   12:27:11.125 memo-mgt-referencecounter-obj-c[2529:10b]
>
> POOL CREATION DEPARTMENT
>
> 2011-07-29 12:27:11.127 memo-mgt-referencecounter-obj-c[2529:10b] 
>   RC=1 of p=
>
> 2011-07-29 12:27:11.128 memo-mgt-referencecounter-obj-c[2529:10b] 
>   RC=1 of p1=
>
> 2011-07-29 12:27:11.129 memo-mgt-referencecounter-obj-c[2529:10b] 
>   RC=1 of p2=
>
> 2011-07-29 12:27:11.129 memo-mgt-referencecounter-obj-c[2529:10b] 
>   RC=1 of p3=
>
> 2011-07-29 12:27:11.130 memo-mgt-referencecounter-obj-c[2529:10b] 
>   RC=1 of p4=
>
> 2011-07-29 12:27:11.130 memo-mgt-referencecounter-obj-c[2529:10b] 
>   OBJECT CREATION DEPARTMENT
>
> 2011-07-29 12:27:11.131 memo-mgt-referencecounter-obj-c[2529:10b] 
>   INITIATING THE CLASS REFERENCE..........RETAIN COUNT=1
>   OBJECT1=
>
> 2011-07-29 12:27:11.132 memo-mgt-referencecounter-obj-c[2529:10b] 
>   INITIATING THE CLASS REFERENCE..........RETAIN COUNT=1
>   OBJECT2=
>
> 2011-07-29 12:27:11.132 memo-mgt-referencecounter-obj-c[2529:10b] 
>   INITIATING THE CLASS REFERENCE..........RETAIN COUNT=1
>   OBJECT3=
>
> 2011-07-29 12:27:11.133 memo-mgt-referencecounter-obj-c[2529:10b] 
>   INITIATING THE CLASS REFERENCE..........RETAIN COUNT=1
>   OBJECT4=
>
> 2011-07-29 12:27:11.134 memo-mgt-referencecounter-obj-c[2529:10b] 
>   INITIATING THE CLASS REFERENCE..........RETAIN COUNT=1
>   OBJECT5=
>
> 2011-07-29 12:27:11.145 memo-mgt-referencecounter-obj-c[2529:10b] 
>   DELETION DEPARTMENT
>
> 2011-07-29 12:27:11.145 memo-mgt-referencecounter-obj-c[2529:10b] 
>   DEALLOCATING THE CLASS REFERENCE..........                                    RETAIN COUNT of
>    to 0                                                                                    And object remain 4
>
> 2011-07-29 12:27:11.146 memo-mgt-referencecounter-obj-c[2529:10b] 
>   DEALLOCATING THE CLASS REFERENCE..........                                                RETAIN COUNT of
>    to 0                                                                                    And object remain 3
>
> 2011-07-29 12:27:11.147 memo-mgt-referencecounter-obj-c[2529:10b] 
>   DEALLOCATING THE CLASS REFERENCE..........                                                RETAIN COUNT of
>    to 0                                                                                    And object remain 2
>
> 2011-07-29 12:27:11.148 memo-mgt-referencecounter-obj-c[2529:10b] 
>   DEALLOCATING THE CLASS REFERENCE..........                                                RETAIN COUNT of
>    to 0                                                                                    And object remain 1
>
> 2011-07-29 12:27:11.149 memo-mgt-referencecounter-obj-c[2529:10b] 
>   DEALLOCATING THE CLASS REFERENCE..........                                                RETAIN COUNT of
>    to 0                                                                                    And object remain 0
>
> 2011-07-29 12:27:11.149 memo-mgt-referencecounter-obj-c[2529:10b]
>                                                 RC=1 of p=
>
> 2011-07-29 12:27:11.150 memo-mgt-referencecounter-obj-c[2529:10b] 
>   RC=1 of p1=
>
> 2011-07-29 12:27:11.151 memo-mgt-referencecounter-obj-c[2529:10b] 
>   RC=1 of p2=
>
> 2011-07-29 12:36:29.419 memo-mgt-referencecounter-obj-c[2583:10b] 
>   RC=1 of p3=
>
> sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all Attaching to process 2583.

In other cases like [p1/p2/p3/p4 release];
the last line O/P is ,-

> 2011-07-29 12:40:38.124 memo-mgt-referencecounter-obj-c[2623:10b] 
>   RC=1 of p=
>
> 2011-07-29 12:40:38.124 memo-mgt-referencecounter-obj-c[2623:10b] 
>   RC=1 of p1=
>
> 2011-07-29 12:40:38.124 memo-mgt-referencecounter-obj-c[2623:10b] 
>   RC=1 of p2=
>
> 2011-07-29 12:40:38.125 memo-mgt-referencecounter-obj-c[2623:10b] 
>   RC=1 of p3=
>
> 2011-07-29 12:40:38.125 memo-mgt-referencecounter-obj-c[2623:10b] 
>   RC=1 of p4=
>
> The Debugger has exited with status 0.

Now my question is where has the p4 pool gone in the case of [p release];
and what is the architecture behind this

Answer (score 1):

retainCount is useless.  Don't call it.

As for autorelease pools, they aren't any kind of a standard behavior object.  Can't be subclasses, don't behave like anything else.  Cannot be introspected.

The documentation and memory management concept guide covers all of this extensively.

---

That you don't see logging output is no indication that any variable or pool or whatever is gone.  It just means the program crashed/exited *before* the log line was written.

Comment: Thanks,But I have asked about the p4 pool of autoreleasepool.

Comment: why in case of [p release], it is not showing p4 and showing in other cases.